# Microsoft Access VBA import .xlsx file issues: "external Table not in the expected format"

Tags: excel, ms-access, import, vba

I am trying to accomplish the following in a access VBA code:

1. Select a file from a folder
2. Convert the file from .csv to .xlsx
3. Import that file into a table in my Access database

I am having trouble with the last step, I am able to covert the file but on import there seems to be an issue with the file format. Getting the following error: " Run-time error'3274' "External table is not in the expected format"

Does anyone know of a possible solution?

Code:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
Dim fd As Office.FileDialog
Dim varFile As Variant

Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

With fd
    .Title = "Choose the File you would like to import"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .InitialFileName = "Z:\location\"
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xls*"
    .Filters.Add "All Files", "*.*"
    .Filters.Add "CSV Files", "*.csv"

    If .Show = True Then
        For Each varFile In .SelectedItems

            Dim xlApp As Object
            Dim wb As Object
            Dim strFile As String

            Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
            strFile = varFile
            Set wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strFile)

            With wb
                ' where 56 is value of excel constant xlExcel8
                .SaveAs FileName:=Replace(strFile, ".csv", ".xlsx"), FileFormat:=51
            End With
            'clean up
            Set wb = Nothing
            xlApp.Quit
            Set xlApp = Nothing

     MsgBox ("Your File has been converted and is currently being imported to this database") 'Should come up as a success

           DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet _
                TransferType:=acImport, _
                SpreadsheetType:=acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, _
                TableName:="C-Report", _
                FileName:=varFile, _
                HasFieldNames:=True
            MsgBox ("Your Import has been complete") 'Should come up as a sucess message
        Next
    Else
        'stop execution if nothing selected
        MsgBox ("There has been an error with your import. Please try again.")
        End
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: A Title that actually describes the issue you are having might help bring more people into help...

Answer (score 0):

In the TransferSpreadsheet, the name of the csv file is being referenced instead of the xlsx file.
Add this line just before that statement:

```
varFile = Left(varFile, (InStrRev(varFile, ".", -1, vbTextCompare) - 1)) & ".xlsx"
```

It will then see the proper filename and complete the transfer successfully.

Comment: Alternatively, OP can pass the replaced file name just as he did in conversion: `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet ...FileName:=Replace(strFile, ".csv", ".xlsx")`

Comment: Good call Parfait!

Comment: Thanks! this works, @tlemaster Can you explain how that line works?

Comment: InStrRev(varFile, ".", -1, vbTextCompare) returns the position of the last period in the filename (in case there is more than one).  The Left command wrapped around that just returns the file name with no suffix.  After that the & ".xlsx" tacks the suffix we want onto the end of the filename.  I hope that makes sense!